# What should be the type of result from select query in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, bq-execute-immediate

For some reason I need to save the result from `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and reuse it in another query as CTE. Since `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` cannot present in CTE, storing it as variable seems to be the last sort.

What should I put for item type of array? The schema of `my_ga4.analytics_9999.events_20220101` is just a normal GA4 table.

Schema can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846

```sql
    DECLARE event_example ARRAY<???>; -- Here

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT(
        "%s", (
            SELECT platform, event_name, event_params FROM `my_ga4.analytics_9999.events_20220101` LIMIT 10
        )
    ) INTO event_example;
```

I have tried

```
    DECLARE event_example ARRAY<
        STRUCT<
            platform STRING,
            event_name STRING,
            event_params ARRAY<
                STRUCT<
                    key STRING,
                    value STRUCT<
                        string_value STRING,
                        int_value    INT64,
                        double_value FLOAT64,
                        float_value  FLOAT64
                    >
                >
            >
        >
    >;
```

Comment: Storing the result of the query in a temporary table not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution fo my case.

```sql
    DECLARE event_example ARRAY<
        STRUCT<
            result STRUCT<
                platform STRING,
                event_name STRING,
                event_params ARRAY<
                    STRUCT<
                        key STRING,
                        value STRUCT<
                            string_value STRING,
                            int_value    INT64,
                            double_value FLOAT64,
                            float_value  FLOAT64
                        >
                    >
                >
            >
        >
    >;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT(
        "%s", (
            WITH
                payload AS (
                    SELECT
                        event_name, platform
                    FROM `my_ga4.analytics_9999.events_20220101`
                    GROUP BY
                        event_name, platform
                )
            SELECT
                'SELECT ARRAY_AGG(result) AS result FROM (' ||
                STRING_AGG(
                        '(SELECT STRUCT(platform, event_name, event_params) FROM `my_ga4.analytics_9999.events_20220101` WHERE event_name = \'' ||
                        event_name
                        || '\' AND platform = \'' ||
                        platform
                        || '\' LIMIT 1)', ' UNION ALL '
                    )
                || ') result'
            FROM payload
        )
        ) INTO event_example;

SELECT event_example;
```